# aws eks list all deployments in a node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli, amazon-eks

Using `aws eks` cli, is there a way that I can list all of my pods in a given nodegroup? if not, is there an alternative? I know I can access this using the AWS Console. But ideally I would like to create a script that does it for me.

Comment: Can you use `kubectl`?

Comment: If you mean do I have access to kubectl, then yes. I am not sure how I can tie up kubectl with EKS nodegroups though? I know I can get access to deployments and their respective nodes. But what about nodegroups?

Comment: Nodes are labeled with their nodegroup name using the `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup` label. You can use this info to find all nodes in the nodegroup and then you can list pods based on those hosts.